# Bind view models' property to dependency property

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding, dependency-properties

I have created reusable components let's say a label and a textbox:

**HeaderAndTextBox.xaml**

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock
            Margin="10,0,0,0"
            FontSize="16"
            FontWeight="DemiBold"
            Foreground="White"
            Text="{Binding Header, ElementName=root}" />

        <TextBox
            Grid.Row="1"
            MaxWidth="300"
            Margin="10"
            mah:TextBoxHelper.ClearTextButton="True"
            mah:TextBoxHelper.IsWaitingForData="True"
            FontSize="16"
            Text="{Binding TextBoxContent, ElementName=root}" />

    </Grid>
```

Now as you can see I created dependency properties for the Text properties. Here is the code behind:

**HeaderAndTextBox.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class HeaderAndTextBox : UserControl
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Header", typeof(string), typeof(HeaderAndTextBox), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

        public string Header
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(HeaderProperty); }
            set { SetValue(HeaderProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextBoxContentProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("TextBoxContent", typeof(string), typeof(HeaderAndTextBox), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

        public string TextBoxContent
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TextBoxContentProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextBoxContentProperty, value); }
        }

        public HeaderAndTextBox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

In my view I use this reusable component like this:

**MyView.xaml**

```
<controls:HeaderAndTextBox
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Margin="10,10,0,0"
                            Header="Last Name"
                            TextBoxContent="{Binding Path=LastName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

And my view model:

**MyViewModel.cs**

```
private string? _lastName;
        public string? LastName
        {
            get
            {
                return _lastName;
            }
            set
            {
                _lastName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(LastName));
            }
        }
```

Question is, how can I bind this dependency property to my view model's property? As my approach doesn't work. I have more than one property so I must find a solution for the binding to be dynamic.
Could it be that for this kind of problem, I should use a completely different approach?

Comment: Make sure the MyViewModel is the DataContext of HeaderAndTextBox. Consider to extend HeaderedContentControl instead of UserControl. UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged is the default and is therefore redundant to specify.

Comment: But I'd like to use this for several view models so I can't set the data context to only one view model. Do you know a workaround solution?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. A control can only have a single object as its DataContext. DataContext is usually inherited but you can also assign it locally.

Comment: I created this control so that I don't duplicate xaml that much. My goal was to use for example this control all over my wpf project. What I wanted to achieve was, in this case, is to bind this control's textbox's text property to my view's view model properties - as I would use this control multiple times on this specific view, but later, on others too. Basically, everything else is working fine but I couldn't make this one to work.

Comment: Do not set the DataContext of HeaderAndTextBox. Set the DataContext of MyView. HeaderAndTextBox will inherit the DataContext value.

Comment: Also note that UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged on the TextBoxContent Binding is pointless. It has no effect on a OneWay Binding like this. You may however want to set it on the Text Binding in the UserControl's  XAML. Then also set the TextBoxContent  Binding to TwoWay, or better, register it so that it binds TwoWay by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The internal elements must bind to the control's properties either by `Binding.ElementName`, where the the named `UserControl` is the binding source or by using `Binding.RelativeSource`.

**HeaderAndTextBox.xaml**

```xml
<UserControl>
  <TextBox Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=TextBoxContent, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
</UserControl>
```

Next, make sure the `DataContext` of the parent element that hosts `HeaderAndTextBox` is correct:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <MyViewModel />
  </Window.DataContext>
  
  <StackPanel>

    <!-- The HeaderAndTextBox inherits the parent's DataContext, 
         which is MyViewModel, automatically. -->
    <HeaderAndTextBox TextBoxContent="{Binding SomeMyViewModelTextProperty}" />

    <Grid DataContext="{Binding GridViewModel}">

      <!-- Same control, different instance, 
           binds to a different view model class (GridViewModel). -->
      <HeaderAndTextBox TextBoxContent="{Binding SomeGridViewModelTextProperty}" />
    </Grid>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

To make the `HeaderAndTextBox.TextBoxContent` property send data back to the view model automatically (when typing into the `TextBox`), you should configure the dependency property accordingly by using a `FrameworkPropertyMetadata` object instead of a `PropertyMetadata` and set the `FrameworkPropertyMetadata.BindsTwoWayByDefault` property:

**HeaderAndTextBox.xaml.cs**

```cs
partial class HeaderAndTextBox : UserControl
{
  public static readonly DependencyProperty TextBoxContentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "TextBoxContent", 
    typeof(string), 
    typeof(HeaderAndTextBox), 
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(string), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

  public string TextBoxContent
  {  
    get => (string)GetValue(TextBoxContentProperty); 
    set => SetValue(TextBoxContentProperty, value); 
  }
}
```

Comment: I followed every step that you mentioned and now the property gets updated whenever the textbox loses focus. Can you make it so that it updates after every character in the textbox? Like PropertyChanged?

Comment: I have updated the binding on the TextBox.text property in HeaderAndTextBox.xaml. TextBoxContent property is now updated on every keystroke.